# Calculating the number of MACs in a system

Tags: filters, homework

I want to calculate the number of MACs. I am looking for the method.

How would I do it if I know the domain equations from a biquadratic digital filter. I have already calculated the Z domain equations, i know X(z), Y(z) and already calculated my zeros and poles, I also have all the A and B values.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you call a MAC in big O notation?  Big MACS

Comment: why the two $H(z)$ formulas? And, considering you already have a processing block diagram, where's the problem reading the number of multiply-accumulates (per output sample, I'd guess? You're not specifying that.) from the block diagram?

Comment: Sorry the a,b,c,d,e values from the block diagram are as follows:a=0.39, b=-0.01, c=0.22, d=-0.65, e =0.02

Comment: you need 5 multiplications and 2 additions.

Comment: I am trying to understand how i calculate the number of MACs the system needs based on the info i have, can you explain what you mean by 5 multiplications and 2 additions?

Comment: In order to calculate a new output sample, you need to perform 5 multiplications and  2 additions. Hint : On your block-diagram you have 5 multiplications and 2 additions

Comment: i took some notes and jotted down, each multiplication and addition is known as a single MAC (multiply and accumulate). I also noted N+1 Macs needed to perform the operation. so my first attempt at the answer is 5 +2 +1 would it be 8 MACs or do i need to factor in the Multiplication factors at each stage or am i overthinking it?